# Remove DIV on mobile devices using jQuery remove

Tags: jquery, wordpress, adsense

I need to remove a div on mobile devices only - my site is responsive - and at the moment i am using css display:none; however i want it to be removed from the DOM completely.

The DIV has google adsense code inside and show is still "showing" up on mobile devices even though the advert does not show - and this is doubling the adverts pageviews and lowering the click through rate unnecessarily.

so how can you remove a DIV using jquery remove at a specific break point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this using screen width:

```
if ($(window).width() < 797) {
  $('#youDiv').remove();
}
```

Change the 797 to whatever breakpoint you want and add your div id in.

Comment: thanks, i thought it was something like that, however the div is still in the DOM..